# Assigning values from one list to another

Tags: python

Is it possible to assign values from one list to another?

```
import pygame
pygame.image.load(enemy.png))
list1 = [0, 200, 400, 600]
list2 = [3, 4, 7, 8]
number = 3
for i in range(number):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('enemy.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.choice(list1))
    enemyY.append(random.choice(list2))
```

I mean if `0` for `enemyX` was chosen, I would like to get `3` in `enemyY` and so on. Is this possible to do without many if statements?

Answer (score 2):

Either zip the lists together to choose an element or choose an index:

```
x, y = random.choice(list(zip(list1, list2)))
```

or

```
indx = random.choice(list(range(len(list1))))
X = list1[indx]
y = list2[indx]
```